# How ref & out works across methods with local variables?

Tags: c#, methods, access-modifiers

We cannot specify access modifiers for fields in a method, The reason I suspect for this is that the fields inside a method (i.e local variables) should have scope only inside that particular method so there is no need to specify the access modifiers.

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int Y;
            Test(out Y);
        }

        private static void Test(out int X)
        {
            X = 17;
        }
    }
```

**Question:**

If scope of method field is within that method then how `ref` and `out` works across methods? I know they are `passed by reference` but how CLR can pass that variables address(reference) when its scope is limited to that particular method?

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx

Comment: because it is meaningless. a local variable can only be accessed in the scope which it's declared.

Comment: @Selman22 - That's fine, that is what I have written in the first line (but probably downvoters didn't read the entire question). But how `ref` & `out` are accessed across methods?

Comment: @RahulSingh they are passed by reference, unlike other parameters. compiler passes the reference, you can think it as an address of the variable. that is how you access the original value in memory. btw, you should probably change the title with your actual question.

Comment: @Selman22 - Updated. Please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If scope of method field is within that method then how ref and out works across methods? I know they are passed by reference but how CLR can pass that variables address(reference) when its scope is limited to that particular method?

The variable address is not bound to it's scope.When you have the address, you can access the object in that address from whereever you want.This address is used whenever you make changes in the `ref` or `out` parameter. Compiler uses that to access and manipulate the actual data.So the scope has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

These are [local variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742(v=vs.71).aspx) which are accessible in the method's code block (`methodName{..code-block-here..}`) scope only and you can't specify any other accessibility level to them - there is no sence to access them from the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to try and declare a `private` variable in a method . Because by default you can't acces a variable outside a method. Variables that you declare in a method are called local variables. So it wouldn't make any sense to be allowed to give it an acces modifier

Answer (score 0):

Modifiers are meant to control external class access to variables.

For example, you might not want any class other than your own to access a variable, or you just want subclasses and classes in the same package to access it. Thats the job of modifiers.

A method variable, however, is not accessible by anything outside of that method, and won't live for longer than the time it takes for the method to complete, so there really no point to having modifiers inside the method. The variable access is fixed as its scope is very limited.